# Generate a JSON body by looping

Tags: json, list, loops, groovy, jmeter

I am trying to generate a JSON request body by looping. I am using groovy for this since this is a JMeter work.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
def outList = [];
for (i = 0; i < ${noDataPoints}; i++) {    
Date latestdate = new Date(); 
outList.add("{\"timestamp\":" + latestdate.getTime() + ",\"value\": 100}")
sleep 1
}
```

Here when I pass a value to `noDataPoints` it gives the following output.

```
[{"timestamp":1597142639466,"value": 100}, {"timestamp":1597142639467,"value": 100}, {"timestamp":1597142639469,"value": 100}, {"timestamp":1597142639470,"value": 100}, {"timestamp":1597142639471,"value": 100}]
```

Now what I want to do is, I want to save the `1st timestamp` of the above list and `last timestamp` of the above list into `2 variables` for further calculations.

Really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to jmeter, it's more of a groovy question. Anyway:

```
firstTimestamp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(outList.first()).'timestamp'
lastTimestamp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(outList.last()).'timestamp'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts as:

   - It may conflict with Groovy [GString template](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html) engine
   - Only [first value will be used](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in case of multiple iterations
   - It may resolve into something causing compilation failure

     so go for `vars.get('noDataPoints')` instead where **vars** is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
2. Using [Thread.sleep() is a some form of a performance antipattern](https://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/), consider incrementing the value instead.
3. You have the counter therefore you can store 1st and last values into the JMeter variables using the aforementioned **vars** shorthand

Suggested amended code:

```
def outList = [];
def noDataPoints = vars.get('noDataPoints') as int
def latestdate = new Date().getTime()
for (i = 0; i < noDataPoints; i++) {
    latestdate++
    if (i == 0) {
        vars.put('1sttimestamp', latestdate as String)
    }
    if (i == noDataPoints - 1) {
        vars.put('lasttimestamp', latestdate as String)
    }
    outList.add("{\"timestamp\":" + latestdate + ",\"value\": 100}")
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)